# How to integrate $e^x / x$

Tags: integration

I was wondering, how can we can calculate the integral of $(e^x)/x$

Thank you

Comment: This is the definition of the exponential integral $\text{Ei}\left(x\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't integrate and express it in terms of elementary functions. To tackle this problem, the exponential integral $\text{Ei}\left(x\right)$ defined as
$$\text{Ei}\left(x\right) = - \int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm{d}t$$
gives answers to such questions. One may get numerical values for these problems.

You can find some info, [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).